# How do I make a specific keyboard input change the properties of shapes on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make it so when the user presses a certain key certain attributes of the shape change. For example, how would I make it so when the user presses "a" on the keyboard the shape onscreen changes colour.

I've tried editing a mouse rollover event to fit the key press input I want it to respond to.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
<style>

.box1{
 background:#1E90FF;
 width: 1000px;
 height:100px;
 float:right;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.circle {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color:  #1E90FF;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.toprectangle {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  float:right;
  margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
  

}

.square {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  float:right;
  margin: 10px 40px 10px 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
  <!--Third square down-->

}
.box2{
 background:#1E90FF;
 width: 1400px;
 height:100px;
 float:right;
 margin: 60px 0px 0px 0px;
 <!--rectangle at the bottom-->
 

}

.box3{
 background:#1E90FF;
 width: 200px;
 height:600px;
 margin: 0px 20px 130px 0px;
 <!--rectangle going up the side-->
}
.circle1{
     height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:  #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px 500px 0px;

}

</style>
</head>



<body>


<script>
 function onkeypress(evt);
 if(onkeypress == 49):
  .toprectangle {
   height: 80px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: #ff78ff;
   float:right;
   margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
   border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
     }

</script>
 <div class="box1"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="circle1"></div>
 <div class="toprectangle"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="box3"></div>
 <div class="box2"></div>
<svg width="500" height="150">  
  

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

.toprectangle {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  float:right;
  margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
  border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
  

}
<script>
 function onkeypress(evt);
 if(onkeypress == 49):
  .toprectangle {
   height: 80px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: #ff78ff;
   float:right;
   margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
   border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
   }
</script>
 <div class="box1"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="circle1"></div>
 <div class="toprectangle"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="box3"></div>
 <div class="box2"></div> 
  

</body>
</html>
```

I expect different shapes to change colour depending on what key the user presses, but the code at the moment does not respond to any input.

Comment: Well, the idea is to toggle dom item classess to change its style.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code.

1: You have CSS styling without enclosing it right in your HTML.

2: Your JavaScript function has errors ( not sure what you're trying to achieve with that function?).

Try this. it changes the background-color when you press Enter (2 examples, Vanilla JavaScript & jQuery):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <style>
        .toprectangle {
            height: 80px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #1E90FF;
            float: right;
            margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
            border: 1px solid #1E90FF;


        }
    </style>

    <script>

        /* WITH VANILLA JAVASCRIPT */
        document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('toprectangle');
                let requiredElement = elements[0];
                requiredElement.style.background = "green";
            }
        };

        /* WITH JQUERY */
        $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {

            if (e.which == 13) { // If you press "Enter" key
                $(".toprectangle").css({
                    "background-color": "green"
                })
            }
        });
    </script>



    <div class="box1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="toprectangle"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using JQuery, in the case of the question is without the JQuery, but if she uses JQuery, your answer would be the way to go

Comment: I editted it and added vanilla JavaScript if you don't want to use jQuery.
But to be honest, jQuery is great for these kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is some things wrong in your code... First thing you JS (JavaScript) is wrong, the syntax

### Wrong way

```
function onkeypress(evt);
    if(onkeypress == 49)
```

### Right way

```
function onkeypress(evt) {

    if ( /* your condition */ ) {
        /* your code */
    }
}
```

---

Also you need to add an listener to your function, the listener will listen to some event and call a function (Your callback), you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). To use it would be like:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", onkeypress); // Add the listener

function onkeypress(e) {
    /* Will handler your callback */
}
```

#### Or

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    /* Will handler your callback */
})
```

And your CSS in the second snnipet is wrong, you must use it inside the `<style></style>` tag. And you `<script></script>` tag must be in the end of the body, to works fine.
Try the code bellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
  <style>
    .toprectangle {
        height: 80px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        float:right;
        margin: 0px 40px 20px 80px;
        border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="toprectangle"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>


  <script>
    document.addEventListener("keypress", onkeypress);
      function onkeypress(e) {
        console.log(`Letter: ${e.key} with code ${e.keyCode}`);
        if (e.keyCode == 97) {
          console.log('Letter `a` has been pressd!');
          let toprectangle = document.getElementsByClassName("toprectangle");
          console.log(toprectangle)
          toprectangle[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000"
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```